# Can I downgrade from .net 2.1 to 2.0 for unit testing purposes

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for some advice please. I have built a web app  in visual studio community edition which leverages on .NET 2.1. 
I want to start unit testing but when referencing the main project in the unit test project I get the error "NET Framework 4.6.1 can not reference a project that targets 2.1. etc. etc." 
I understand that .NET Framework will not support .NET Standard 2.1 or any other later version anymore. 
Would you have any advice on whether it would make sense to downgrade to .NET Standard 2.0 (assuming that is possible and I apologise if the question is stupid) or do I risk messing up the entire thing and therefore I should explore alternatives (for which I am happy to do my own research). 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don’t you create your unit test in .net core, not .net framework?

Comment: Thanks Lesiak, I was clearly approaching this from the wrong angle. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create your unit test project in .Net Core, not in .Net framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/